# Hi. How to use find query in mongoose - Express + MongoDB base

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

What I'm doing is trying to write logic for cart in my web-app what I'm creating. Problem what I'm dealing right now is that when I use query to find cart by id :

```
   const isCart = await cartModel.findById("5f82372f2654ce1d18553ac4");
```

or like this

```
   const isCart = await cartModel.find({ _id : "5f82372f2654ce1d18553ac4"} );
```

if cart exist with this id all works good it returns me this cart, but if in DB cart doesn't exist with this id then it throws me an error. WHY (pic below) ?? It would make more sense if it returns empty array or object so I can continue building logic of I want to do. But once it throws error it shuts down all further logic. I can't write if there is nothing found, create new cart and so on. Hopefully you got what I mean. Is it something I don't write correctly query or it is the way it is. If so, then I guess I should already control it on client side - if it returns error to a client side then client side sends new request to a new rout on creating a new cart and so on...

[image]

Here is solution what I did after someone told me that I might try do with try - catch

Here is a result, it works I'm not sure if this solution is right tho

```
async function sendCart (code, cart, res){
    res.status(code).json({
        status: "success",
        data: {
            cart
        }
    })
}

exports.createCart = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const isCart = await cartModel.findById(req.params.id);
        await sendCart(200, isCart, res);
    }
    catch(error){
        const newCart = await cartModel.create({ items: [] });
        await sendCart(201,newCart, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: The application seems to be crashing due to an unhandled promise rejection. If the cart doesn't exists, it will return an error, but you're not treating it, so you're getting the unhandled promise rejection error. Since you're using the asnyc/await syntax, you can probably solve this problem with a try/catch block.

Comment: I see. Let me try

Comment: I did it it works, edited in my post

Comment: does it change if you query by `new ObjectId("5f82372f2654ce1d18553ac4")` - you will have to require it from mongoose `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;`